# upvotes on accepted answers, daily cap reached

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Is there a bug on SO or something wrong with my account?

I've hit the daily rep cap and I've got upvotes (during the same day) on some of my accepted answers **without** a corresponding increase in rep.

It isn't the first time this happens.

Comment: Define "this morning".

Comment: @mmyers: during the same day. I'll update.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at UTC time and not local time?

Comment: @mmyers: I am using the UTC as per the info on the /users/recent/ page down at the bottom.

Comment: Am I missing something or isn't this the designed behaviour of the daily rep cap - to limit the increase in rep from upvotes to the daily rep cap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, my [rep tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=171461&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true) certainly reckons you've hit the rep cap.

When you say "without a corresponding increase in rep" are you suggesting you were on exactly 12173 rep at the start of the UTC day?

If you're wondering why you haven't broken *through* the rep cap: it's not votes on accepted answers that are immune to the limit - it's the 15 point bonus for having an answer accepted. It's not entirely clear from your question, but it's possible that you've got slightly the wrong end of the stick about the rep cap.

Comment: Ah! I have misinterpreted a post on this subject then: the +15 on accepted answers is immune to the cap but **not** upvotes on **already accepted** answers. Thanks!